# Getting final weights and biases values from neural network MLPClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

From the documentation

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html

it is not clear whether the attributes

`coefs_` and `intercepts_`

are the *initial* ones (before the neural network is estimated) or the *final* ones (after the neural network is estimated).

In case they are the final ones, how can one get the initial ones? In case they are the initial ones, how can one get the final ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes `coefs_` and `intercepts_` are the *final* ones. Indeed, [by design](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#estimated-attributes)

> Attributes that have been estimated from the data must always have a name ending with trailing underscore.

The starting values of such parameters are not exposed via a public attribute or method; instead, they are exploiting the [_init_coef()](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3f51f9b611bf873bd5836748647221480071a87/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L360) method to *Glorot-initialize* parameters (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3f51f9b611bf873bd5836748647221480071a87/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L344).

Comment: Thanks, @amiola, for your very clarifying answer! From what you mention, I suspect that, to know what initial values are, we need to create our own `_init_coef()` method, to override the default one.

Comment: Indeed. I agree!